# "Частичная" десериализация объекта

Tags: c#, json

В ответ на запрос к API я получаю `json` следующей структуры:

```
[ 
  { "address": "someaddress",
    "code": "ABC12345",
    "type": "sometype",
    "category": "somecategory"
    // + еще около 40 свойств
   }, 
   ...// такие же объекты
]
```

Из всего этого мне нужны только два поля `"code"` и `"type"`, точнее массив объектов `SomeType`:

```
SomeType
{
   public string code { get; set; }
   public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Класса, по типу которого сериализуется такой объект у меня нет.

В связи с этим два вопроса:

1) Есть ли смысл создавать такой класс, описывать 40+ полей, если нигде кроме десериализации он использоваться не будет?

2) Есть ли возможность "частичной" десериализации объекта?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Да, использование класса, определённого только для десериализации *может* иметь смысл, т. к. при этом вы проверяете не только несколько полей, а всю структуру, и ловите возможные ошибки. Но это довольно трудоёмкая штука, так что выбирайте сами.
2. Да, есть. Один из методов в ответе @gil9red, другой смотрите ниже.

---

Альтернативой к `dynamic` может быть использование [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) (тоже из JSON.NET):

```
var arr = JArray.Parse(json);
var result =
    arr.Select(item =>
            new SomeType() { code = (string)item["code"], type = (string)item["type"] })
       .ToList();
```

Результат:

```
foreach (var st in result)
    Console.WriteLine($"(code = {st.code}, type = {st.type})");
```

выдаёт

```
(code = ABC12345, type = sometype)
(code = XYZ98765, type = someothertype)
```

Comment: Мне Ваш больше способ подходит. Спасибо

Comment: @Sv__t: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD, DeserializeObject тот же JObject возвращал, dynamic там просто для обращения через точку

Answer (score 6):

Из [примера](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17842600/5909792) разбора JSON:

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': { 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY' }, 'Age': 42 }");

string name = stuff.Name;
string address = stuff.Address.City;
```